# Magento 1 Request parameters get null array in controller

Tags: php, linux, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

**Magento 1 Issue**

I have an issue in getting request parameters values from URL. Same code in the local server and the live server. But in the local server have worked fine. but the issue in live server request parameters can't get it gets the null array of request parameters values from URL.

In Local Url :

http://local_url/tesmapi/customer/login?uid=test@test.com&pwd=test

Output :

```
Array
(
    [uid] => test@test.com
    [pwd] => test
)
```

In Live Server Url :

http://live_url/tesmapi/customer/login?uid=test@test.com&pwd=test

Output :

```
Array
(
)
```

Below code in customerController.php

```
public function loginAction() {

    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($params);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

FYI: I have also tried below code but getting null value from URL in live server.

```
$uid = Mage::app ()->getRequest ()->getParam ( 'uid' );
$pwd = Mage::app ()->getRequest ()->getParam ( 'uid' );
```

and I have also tried to print $_GET but not working on the live server.

Can anyone please help me what I'm missing here on the live server.

Comment: is there any rewrite rule on your server??

Comment: Thanks, @NID for a reply. I don't know about it in the server? How can I check it in the server?

Comment: I have used nginx server